# TypeScript React app not rendering after create-react-app --template typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, create-react-app

I created a TypeScript React app using `npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm --template typescript`.

After starting the development server (`cd my-app` `npm start`), the code compiles successfully but when the browser window opens up, nothing is rendered.

Console says: *Worker registration successful http://localhost:3000/* (but still nothing renders)

But also sometimes: *Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'*

I normally have no problems with `create-react-app` for JavaScript, but somehow with TypeScript, this causes issues. I tried using different versions of node (**14.0.0, 15.0.0, 15.0.1**) (npm version **7.0.2**) and other commands (`npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm --typescript` (which probably does the same)) but this didn't help.

The generated *.tsconfig* file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The generated dependencies in my *package.json* file:

```js
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
  "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
  "@types/node": "^12.19.16",
  "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
  "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
  "typescript": "^4.1.5",
  "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
},
```

Comment: for which file it is showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` ? If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, you should uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.
Global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported.

Comment: I get the `expected expression` error when I delete some of the test files and service worker, I'm going to check if I have installed create-react-app globally but I don't think that is the case.

Comment: was it working before you deleted anything?

Comment: No, it never rendered anything in the browser

Comment: The console didn't display any error, but the screen was white

Comment: you may follow this doc, this might help https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Comment: have you tried this command without --use-npm `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` ?

Comment: I am logged in on a company's npm system so that I can download their specific packages, since npx uses yarn to download the packages I get an error that I have to use npm, that is the reason I use the flag. If I use ´npx create-react-app my-app´, the only thing I get is an yarn-error.log file.

Comment: I tried using `npm init react-app` but this didn't help.

Comment: uninstall node and fresh install the latest stable version of node this might help https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: The packages were getting fetched from my company's server which I don't have access to at home, I commented out my `.npmrc` file for working at home and now I can download via yarn again, thank you for your help.